# Is It Fundamentally Correct To The Text Classification Model To Train First Without Pre-Trained Word Vectors And Then With Pre-Trained Word Vectors?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, text-processing, text-classification

Is this solution fundamentally correct to the text classification (sentiment analysis) model to train it by these three steps:

1. train the model without pre-trained word vectors until reaches the minimum loss or maximum accuracy or even stopped by a callback.
2. get the embedding layer weights and substitute the weights of the words which are represented in pre-trained word vectors and lock the embedding layer.
3. train the model again with the embedding layer which includes weights of the known pre-trained word vectors represented in it and unknown pre-trained word vectors based on the previous training.

thanks for your companion

Comment: It would be helpful to give more details of the architecture of the model you are training.  Also, where was the scheme you describe suggested? Do you have a book or paper reference?

Comment: No, there is no paper or reference at all. it was just an ignition in my mind because as you know the embedding layer with assigned zero values for the unknown words  in pre-trained vectors will not be helpful as expected, so tried to explore many ways to merge the known word vectors from pre-trained ones and unknown word vectors only by training the model; so there must be a clue to lead into an useful method but how. and i only asked to know is it fundamentally correct or not, thank you. @DarrenCook

Comment: Architecture description would help. E.g. Is this a transformer model? (If so, how are you encoding? SentencePiece or something else?)